# how can i replace a string from another string in all places of its occuerance.. do we have replace all in node

Tags: node.js, replace

I wrote the below code to replace all }, with ; but only the first ocurance is getting replaced ,other all remains same..

```
data1 = "latitude:1.9,longitude:103.57},latitude:1.338,longitude:103.1},latitude:1.33,longitude:103.7556}"
var re = '},'
data = data1.replace(re,';')
```

I am getting the output like

```
"latitude:1.9,longitude:103.57;latitude:1.338,longitude:103.1},latitude:1.33,longitude:103.7556}"
```

expected output

```
"latitude:1.9,longitude:103.57;latitude:1.338,longitude:103.1;latitude:1.33,longitude:103.7556}"
```

Comment: Use `data1.replace(/'},'/g,';')` with the global flag

Comment: I tried that too but not working

Comment: See https://ideone.com/nMeXsN

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace all occurrences of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - using a regex to do a global search

```
data1 = "latitude:1.9,longitude:103.57},latitude:1.338,longitude:103.1},latitude:1.33,longitude:103.7556}"
var re = /},/g
data1.replace(re, ';')
```

Should return

```
latitude:1.9,longitude:103.57;latitude:1.338,longitude:103.1;latitude:1.33,longitude:103.7556}
```